# How do I include a hyphen in a hyperlink Regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to find links in user entered text and convert them to link automatically.

I am using current Regex as following, which good to find hyperlinks from text.

```
Regex regexResolveUrl = new Regex("((http://|www\\.)([A-Z0-9.-:]{1,})\\.[0-9A-Z?;~&#=\\-_\\./]{2,})", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It is working good for almost all links so far i came across but it is giving problem when i want to detect links with hypen.

i.e. www.abc-xyz.com will not work, with above regex, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the hyphen:

```
 Regex("((http://|www\\.)([A-Z0-9.\-:]{1,})\\.[0-9A-Z?;~&#=\\-_\\./]{2,})", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Aaron, you answered my question, but just to update it would be \\ while doing so, i.e.

Regex("((http://|www\\.)([A-Z0-9.\\-:]{1,})\\.[0-9A-Z?;~&#=\\-_\\./]{2,})", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: @Maria: The double backslash is not part of the regex, it's part of C# string mechanics. Don't confuse escaping mechanisms!

Comment: Tomalak is right, sorry about that, I forgot it was C# for a minute.

Comment: You should be using escaped strings: @"..." rather than standard strings.

Answer (score 8):

If you want `-` to mean dash literally in a character class definition, you need to put it as the last (or first) character. So `[abc-]` is a character class containing 4 characters, `a`, `b`, `c`, `-`. On the other hand, `[ab-c]` only contains 3 characters, not including the `-`, because `-` is a range definition.

So, something like this (from your pattern):

```
[A-Z0-9.-:]
```

Defines 3 ranges, from `A` to `Z`, from `0` to `9`, and from `.` (ASCII 46) to `:` (ASCII 58). You want instead:

```
[A-Z0-9.:-]
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

---

#### Note on repetition

I noticed that you used `{1,}` in your pattern to denote "one-or-more of".

.NET regex (like most other flavors) support these shorthands:

- `?`: "zero-or-one" `{0,1}`
- `*`: "zero-or-more" `{0,}`
- `+`: "one-or-more" `{1,}`

They may take some getting used to, but they're also pretty standard.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

#### Related questions

- [Using explicitly numbered repetition instead of question mark, star and plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus)

---

#### Note on C# `@`-quoted string literals

While doubling the slashes in string literals for regex pattern is the norm in e.g. Java (out of necessity), in C# you actually have an option to use `@`-quoted string literals.

That is, these pairs of strings are identical:

```
"(http://|www\\.)"
@"(http://|www\.)"

"c:\\Docs\\Source\\a.txt"
@"c:\Docs\Source\a.txt"
```

Using `@` can lead to more readable regex patterns because a literal slash don't have to be doubled (although on the other hand, a double quote must now in turn be doubled).

#### References

- [MSDN / C# Programmer's Reference / `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: The alternative is to escape the dash `\-`, but personally I prefer putting it at the end of the range, too.

Answer (score 2):

Add the hyphen as the first or last character in the character class.