# What is the most efficient way to remove every other character from a string?

Tags: java, string

[Removing every other character in a string using Java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166407/removing-every-other-character-in-a-string-using-java-regex)

The code at the above link clearly details how to remove every other character from a string, however, I do not understand how it works and would like to so I can use it in the future. The Oracle page for replaceAll does not mention this type of use.  What is the function of the $1 and the periods and the parentheses (I get that the one in parentheses is the one that is kept, but why, etc.?  Thanks! :)

Comment: `Do I have to use a loop?` - that is how you make your code generic. When done properly it doesn't matter is your string has 3 or 300 characters.

Comment: Yeah why not. Just use a for loop running through the string and adding every other character to a different string. or there might be some regex expression you can do.

Comment: Detail about search patterns can be found in the documentation of the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, the replacement is documented in the backend method [`appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Please be aware that questions have to be self-contained. Now it completely depends on another SO question...

Answer (score -2):

Just use a loop to remove every other character.

```
for (int i = 0; i<yourString.length(); i++){
if (i % 2 != 0){
yourString.deleteCharAt(i);
}
}
```

Comment: What is `deleteCharAt`?