# How do I remove every second character in all line with Emeditor

Tags: text, editor, edit, emeditor

Example:

```
hRihdNeI
```

After removing letters: R , h , N , I

We get letter:

```
hide
```

Please note that there will be million of lines, all lines will have different length, they can be 5 characters long or even 50 characters long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **EmEditor**, open the file, press `Ctrl` + `H` to open the **Replace** dialog box, click **Advanced...** and click **Reset** button to make sure all options are default, click **OK**.

In the **Replace** dialog box, enter:

**Find**: `(.).`

**Replace with**: `\1`

Set **Regular Expressions** and **Match Case** options, and click **Replace All** button.

After replacing all, some versions of EmEditor might have trouble refreshing the editor view. You can scroll up and down to see the changes. You can also press `Alt` + `F3` to erase matching highlight. Finally, you can click the **File** menu, **Save As** to save the result as a different file name. I tested with a 10 million random ASCII text file.

Reference: [Removing every other character in a string using Java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166407/removing-every-other-character-in-a-string-using-java-regex)