# Allow literal . in regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

```
^[a-zA-Z]:{1}/(\w+/)+$
```

I want to allow `.` as well in the expression in `\w+`.  How can I do this?

Comment: `{1}` is completely redundant, by the way, `:{1}` makes **:** match only once, which is the same as `:`.

Comment: To add to Kobi's excellent point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\.` should do it.  You don't need the escaping `\` if you put it in a character class.  For your exact example:

```
^[a-zA-Z]:{1}/([\w.]+/)+$
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.` is a [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in regular expression syntax, so you have to escape it with a backslash.  `\.`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
(\w+/)
```

with

```
([\w.]+/)
```

Answer (score -1):

The expression should be `^[a-zA-Z]:/(\w+./)+$` or `^[a-zA-Z]:/([\w.]+/)+$`

Comment: Um, no? Now you're matching one alnum character `\w` and any character `.` where the OP wants one or more alnums or dots, followed by a slash, repeated once or more.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but as I wrote above, your answer is plain wrong.

Comment: understood. thanks! I thought for a moment that \w is for a word