# regular expression very slow on fail

Tags: ruby, regex, optimization

I've a regular expression that should validate if a string is composed by space-delimited strings. The regular expression works well (ok it allows a empty space in the end ... but that's not he problem) but takes too long when the validation fails.

The regular expression is the following:

```
/^(([\w\-]+)( )?){0,}$/
```

When trying to validate with the string

```
"'this-is_SAMPLE-scope-123,this-is_SAMPLE-scope-456'"
```

it takes 2 seconds.

The tests were performed in ruby 1.9.2-rc1 and 1.8.7. But this is probably a general problem.

Any idea?

Comment: FWIW, it seems OK here on 1.9.1, I've just tried `/^(([\w-]+)( )?){0,}$/.match "'this-is_SAMPLE-scope-123,this-is_SAMPLE-scope-456'"` and it returns `nil` instantly.

Comment: with ruby 1.9.1 i'm getting the following results with Benchmark module:

       user     system      total        real
   2.020000   0.010000   2.030000 (  2.024168)

Comment: @miguel: give examples of what you're trying to match, and what you don't want to match. The more examples the better; make sure they cover all of your cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your pattern causes [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). The catastrophic part can be summarized to this:

```
(.+)*
```

The `+` and the `*` interacts in catastrophic ways in some engines.

It's unclear what you're trying to match, exactly, but it may be something like this:

```
^[\w\-]+( [\w\-]+)*$
```

This matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/BTRKHBzTuS)):

```
hello world
99 bottles of beer on the wall
this_works_too
```

and rejects:

```
not like this, not like this
hey what the &#@!
too many    spaces
```

Another option would be to use possessive quantifiers and/or atomic groupings in parts of the original pattern.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [Atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)

---

#### Additional tips

The `{0,}` repetition is usually written simply as `*`. You can also use non-capturing groups to improve performance, i.e. `(?:pattern)`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

#### Related questions

- [Using explicitly numbered repetition instead of question mark, star and plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus)

Comment: Thanks, with your solution the benchmark shows the following results: 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000021)

Also thanks for the tips.

Comment: Here's a demonstration of the catastrophic backtracking in the original pattern: `^(x+)*$` on input string `xxxxxxxxxxx!` -- http://www.rubular.com/r/swdpfK3HOY -- add more `x` and eventually rubular will time-out.