# Why does this line cause Javascript to crash?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

This line in Chrome/NodeJS causes it to crash. How come?

In the Chrome, it causes the browser tab to hang with no error message.

```
"www.asite.com/clothes-intimates-bras-bralettes/sub5-sub6-sub7-sub8".replace(/.*?([\w\s-]*)+\/?$/, 'www.asite.com/product/$1')
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting in the console when it crashes?

Comment: Firefox: "InternalError: an error occurred while executing regular expression" -- Your regex must be the problem. Post the expected output.

Comment: Looks like the `([\w\s-]*)+` causes to much backtracking and the engine gets in a weird state, or something like that. Doesn't happen when the `+` is removed. Solution: design your expression more carefully.

Comment: Has to be a backtracking issue.  This hung the Chrome console without an error message and totally froze up the tab.  Had to shut down chrome to get rid of it.

Comment: It just kills the browser in chrome.

Comment: I'm just curious why exactly this happens. Of course I changed the code.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3212256/218196. It links to http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to examine your regular expression in pieces to understand what's going on.  Here's the original.

```
.*?([\w\s-]*)+\/?$
```

And the breakdown:

```
.*?
```

. = anything, * = zero or more, and ? = non-greedy.

```
([\w\s-]*)+
```

() = capture, [] = a group, \w = alphanumerics, \s = spaces, - = dashes, * = zero or more, + = one or more.

```
\/?
```

? = may or may not occur.

So essentially you're asking to match anything followed by a potentially empty group of charaters, spaces, or dashes which must occur once which is perhaps followed by a slash anchored to the end of the input string.  The variable length matches `.*`  and `([\w\s-]*)+` create a potentially infinite set of matches when the regular expression engine starts backtracking.

Your expression matches null (empty string) just as well as it matches `-sub8` just as well as it matches `www.asite.com/clothes-intimates-bras-bralettes/sub5-sub6-sub7-sub8`.  Or it could match .*? as nothing, followed by 7000 ([\w\s-] *) captures of nothing (remember * means nothing), then a final ([\w\s-] *) capture of the last character '8'...   Sorry to beat on, I'm just trying to get you to an intuitive understanding of the significance of a `([] *)+` style capture.

The expression seems to be a result of not translating exactly what you're intending to match into a regular expression pattern correctly.  What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: FWIW, changing the part to `([\w\s-]+)+` exposes the same problem though. So, I don't think that `([]*)+` matches infinitely, but it does get into a bad/weird state.