# Mapping String contents key/value pairs to a HashMap

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to establish some way of mapping a String document to a HashMap as follows:

the String contains key/value pair

```
$key1=value1
$key2=value2 value21
value22
$key3=value3
```

what I want to end up with is:

```
key1, value1
key2, value2 value21\nvalue22
key3, value3
```

Is there a pattern I can use for this? It looks like an interesting puzzle, so far I have come up with using `split("[$]{1}[A-Za-z]+[=]{1}")` to separate the different values but then it has to be a different iteration to identify the keys, so I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Don't bother with `{1}` repetition specifier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use two regex here:
`\$(\w+)=((\w+\s*)+)` will separate keys from values
`(\s+)` to split values.

```
String input = "$key1=value1\n" +
        "$key2=value2 value21\n" +
        "value22\n" +
        "$key3=value3";

Pattern keyValuePattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\w+)=((\\w+\\s*)+)");
Matcher keyValueMatcher = keyValuePattern.matcher(input); // get a matcher object
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
while (keyValueMatcher.find()) {
    String key = keyValueMatcher.group(1);
    List<String> values;
    values = Arrays.asList(keyValueMatcher.group(2).split("\\s+"));
    //If you want to update your lists later comment the line above and uncomment those two
    //values = new ArrayList<String>();
    //values.addAll(Arrays.asList(keyValueMatcher.group(2).split("\\s+")));

    map.put(key, values);
}

System.out.println(map); // {key3=[value3], key2=[value2, value21, value22], key1=[value1]}
```

NB: You could use `\$(\w+)=(.*)` as regex too, it depends on what you want to match, in the case above, every word/number separated by spaces, in this case, anything.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you may take a look to the [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) files.

You can use the [Properties.load(InputStream)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) to read entries from files using:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
     .getResourceAsStream("file.properties"));
```

or even from a String using:

```
String myString = new String("first=1");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new StringBufferInputStream(myString));
```

You can find more information regarding formatting in the [Properties.load(InputStream)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) doc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the complete text is in a string (= *not* read line by line), then you can work with multiple splits:

```
String input = "$key1=value1\n$key2=value2 value21\nvalue22\n$key3=value3";
String[] lines = input.split("\n");
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


StringBuilder value = null;
String key = null;
for (String line:lines) {
  if (line.contains('=')) {
    if (key != null) {
      // store the actual k/v pair before starting a new one
      map.put(key, value.toString());
    } else {
      // create a new k/v pair
      String[] temp = line.split("=");
      key = temp[0];
      value = new StringBuilder(temp[1]);
    }
  } else {
    // we have a value that belongs to the last k/v pair
    value.append("\n").append(line);
}
map.put(key, value.toString());
```

The solution might need some fine-tuning but should work in principle.

Comment: This is pretty much what I have at the moment and it _doesn't_ work. In the above example keyValuePairs[2] does not contain a $key=
In any case, I appreciate your reply.

Comment: ... sorry, my mistake. I'll find the correct solution, hold on, please.

Comment: ... that's better. We store a k/v pair after we're sure, we've read all chars for the value. A new line containing a key triggers the storing of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear *exactly* what your boundaries and delimiters are.  In the case of your example, I'm guessing the delimiters are the `$` at the start of the line which is followed by a "word" (composed of `\w` characters) then an `=` symbol.

If we make a simplifying assumption and say that a `$` at the start of the line is the delimiter (regardless of what follows) then we can do something like this:

```
(?xms:    # Switch on "x" (comment-mode), "m" (Allow "^" to mean start of line rather than start-of-input), "s" (dot-all)
   ^ \$   # Match $ at start of line only
   ( [^=]+ )   # Then capture everything until the next '=' (you may want to use \w+ here)
   =           # Skip the =
   (
     (?: 
        (?! \n (?: ^ \$ | \z ) )  # Stop if we reach the \n before the next $ at the start of a line or the \n at the end of the input
        .           # Otherwise accept any character (including \n thanks to dot-all mode)
     )  *
   )    # This will capture everything (excluding the trailing newline) up to the next $ at the start of the line (or all the way to the end of the input)
)
```

You can then use this in a loop:

```
static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( " <the above RE> ");
  . . .
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myInputString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
}
```

(I haven't tested any of this at all but it should get you started)