# Amount of repetitions of symbols in Lua pattern setup

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm looking for amount of repetitions of symbols in Lua pattern setup.
I try to check amount of symbols in a string.
As I read in [manual](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial), 
Even with character classes this is still very limiting, because we can only match strings with a fixed length.

> To solve this, patterns support these four repetition operators:
>
> - '*' Match the previous character (or class) zero or more times, as many times as possible.
> - '+' Match the previous character (or class) one or more times, as many times as possible.
> - '-' Match the previous character (or class) zero or more times, as few times as possible.
> - '?' Make the previous character (or class) optional.

So, no information about Braces `{}`
e.g.,

```
{1,10}; {1,}; {10};
```

doesn't work.

```
local np = '1'
local a =  np:match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1}$' )
```

returns `np = nil`.

```
local np = '1{1}'
local a =  np:match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1}$' )
```

returns `np = '1{1}'` :)

This [url](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) says that no such magic symbols:

> Some characters, called magic characters, have special meanings when
>   used in a pattern. The magic characters are
>
> ```
> ( ) . % + - * ? [ ^ $
> ```

Curly brackets do work only as simple text and no more.
Am I right? What is the best way to avoid this 'bug'?

It is possible to read usual usage of braces, for instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3032751/1979882).

Comment: Lua do not provide it. You can repetition byself e.g.(`\d{2,}` is `%d%d+`). Also you can use Lua rex pcre library.

Comment: @moteus, very monstrous and ugly usability. but thanks for the idea.

Comment: Lua pattern doesn't support full set of Perl regex features.  Braces are not supported.  Use explicit count: `np:match('^'..('[%w_]'):rep(k)..'$')`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, doesn't it dramatically increase the calculations?

Comment: @trololo - Regex had never been a fast thing.  It's always CPU-intensive.  Search for another approaches to calculate faster: `#np==k and not np:find'[^%w_]'`

Comment: Another limitation for the supported quantifiers: *Unlike some other systems, in Lua a modifier can only be applied to a character class; there is no way to group patterns under a modifier.* Try with PCRE library: `> require "rex_pcre"
>  return rex_pcre.new("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{2}$"):exec("12")`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I think you are right: to check string length in my simple case beforehand is the most usable solution without using external libraries.

Comment: @stribizhev, thanks, i will try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't but admit that Lua regex quantifiers are very limited in functionality.

1. They are just those 4 you mentioned (`+`, `-`, `*` and `?`)
2. *No limiting quantifier support* (the ones you require)
3. Unlike some other systems, in Lua a modifier can only be applied to a character class; there is no way to group patterns under a modifier (see [source](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)). [*Unfortunately Lua patterns do not support this (`'(foo)+'` or `'(foo|bar)'`), only single characters can be repeated or chosen between, not sub-patterns or strings.*](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial)

As a "work-around", in order to use *limiting quantifiers* and all other PCRE regex perks, you can use [`rex_pcre` library](http://rrthomas.github.io/lrexlib/).

Or, as @moteus suggests, a partial workaround **to "emulate" limiting quantifiers having just the lower bound**, just repeat the pattern to match it several times and apply the available Lua quantifier to the last one. E.g. to match *3 or more occurrences* of a pattern:

```
local np = 'abc_123'
local a = np:match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]+$' )
```

See  [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/E2M7Kr)

Another library to consider instead of PCRE is [Lpeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html).

Comment: Thanks for the summarize of the comments.

Comment: Just noting: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be replaced with `[_%w]` which would shorten that pattern a fair bit.

Comment: You could also use the `string.rep` function, e.g. `if np:match(("x"):rep(50))` to match 50 `x` characters

Comment: @jonasstr Yes, just that way we need to use some code already, and in my answer, I was more focusing on what can be done with pure Lua patterns. And that was answered 7 years ago when I knew Lua much worse.