# Lua pattern matching 4 digits that follow "Conference 10-"

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have some string data that I need to search through to find a specific number:

Here's a sample string/buffer:

```
Conference 11-2222-a.b.c (1 member rate: 32000 flags: running|answered|enforce_min|dynamic|exit_sound|enter_sound) 176;014802813@mydomain;0182e4e4-193b-4d63-9bef-b597f0655c83;jdo ;014802813;hear|speak|talking|floor;0;0;0;0

Conference 10-1234.c.fdf.c (1 member rate: 32000 flags: running|answered|enforce_min|dynamic|exit_sound|enter_sound)175;.net/4122@mydomain;77c1f301-85e1-4275-9c539e5927b87d6;4122;hear|speak|talking|floor;0;0;0;0
```

What I need to do is search through this output and the 4 digits that follow "Conference 10-".  In this case it is 1234 that I'm after.

**What I've tried **

I've tried all the following patterns... none of which are giving me what I need:

```
  print(string.match(input, "10-%d%d%d%d-"));
  print(string.match(input, "Conference 10-%d%d%d%d-"));
  print(string.match(input, "Conference 10-(%d)-");
  print(string.match(input, "Conference 10(\-)(%d));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the hyphen with `%` as **unescaped `-` is a lazy quantifier in Lua** (*`-`   also 0 or more repetitions*).

```
str = "Conference 11-2222-a.b.c (1 member rate: 32000 flags: running|answered|enforce_min|dynamic|exit_sound|enter_sound) 176;014802813@mydomain;0182e4e4-193b-4d63-9bef-b597f0655c83;jdo ;014802813;hear|speak|talking|floor;0;0;0;0\n\nConference 10-1234.c.fdf.c (1 member rate: 32000 flags: running|answered|enforce_min|dynamic|exit_sound|enter_sound)175;.net/4122@mydomain;77c1f301-85e1-4275-9c539e5927b87d6;4122;hear|speak|talking|floor;0;0;0;0"
print(string.match(str, 'Conference 10%-(%d%d%d%d)') )
                                      ^
```

This [will print `1234`](http://ideone.com/d9TBKj).

From the [Lua *20.2 – Patterns* reference](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html):

> Some characters, called magic characters, have special meanings when used in a pattern. The magic characters are
>
> `( ) . % + - * ? [ ^ $`
>
> The character `%` works as an escape for those magic characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub()`:

```
print(string.gsub(".*Conference 10%-(%d%d%d%d)%-.*", "%1"));
```

Comment: @stribizhev already fixed :) ( just reading the manual now - I wonder why it was felt necessary to not use standard regex?)

Comment: There is no point in using `gsub` since `match` will only return captured substrings if capture groups are defined in the pattern.

Comment: You can read about the limitations in [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884090/amount-of-repetitions-of-symbols-in-lua-pattern-setup/32885308#32885308).

Comment: @str right. I went this way because that's how one would do it in Java (and this is my first attempt at answering a Lua Q).