# Lua gsub - How to set max character limit in regex pattern

Tags: regex, lua, gsub

From strings that are *similar* to this string:

`|cff00ccffkey:|r value`

I need to remove |cff00ccff and |r to get:

`key: value`

The problem is that `|cff00ccff` is a color code. I know it always starts with `|c` but **the next 8 characters** could be anything. So I need a gsub pattern to get the next 8 characters (alpha-numeric only) after `|c`.

How can I do this in Lua? I have tried:

```
local newString = string.gsub("|cff00ccffkey:|r value", "|c%w*", "")
newString = string.gsub(newString, "|r", "")
```

but that will remove everything up to the first white-space and I don't know how to specify the max characters to select to avoid this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua patterns [do not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884090/amount-of-repetitions-of-symbols-in-lua-pattern-setup) range/interval/limiting quantifiers.

You may repeat `%w` alphanumeric pattern eight times:

```
local newString = string.gsub("|cff00ccffkey:|r value", "|c%w%w%w%w%w%w%w%w", "")
newString = string.gsub(newString, "|r", "")
print(newString)
-- => key: value
```

See the [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/JCe46l).

You may also make it a bit more dynamic if you build the pattern like  `('%w'):.rep(8)`:

```
local newString = string.gsub("|cff00ccffkey:|r value", "|c" ..('%w'):rep(8), "")
```

See [another Lua demo](https://ideone.com/vefWrm).

If your strings always follow this pattern -  `|c<8alpnum_chars><text>|r<value>` - you may also use a pattern like

```
local newString = string.gsub("|cff00ccffkey:|r value", "^|c" ..('%w'):rep(8) .. "(.-)|r(.*)", "%1%2")
```

See [this Lua demo](https://ideone.com/uLMdUy)

Here, the pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `|c` - a literal `|c`
- `" ..('%w'):rep(8) .. "` - 8 alphanumeric chars
- `(.-)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `|r` - a `|r` substring
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the string.

The `%1` and `%2` refer to the values captured into corresponding groups.

Comment: And there is definitely no easier/nicer way to specify the number of %w needed?

Comment: @Mayron If you mean a [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), no, it is not possible.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know if there was a nice way of possibly combining those 2 gsub calls by using a regex pattern to say something like "only substitute things that are inside these brackets" (like how c# can assign matches of text to groups): `"(|c%w%w%w%w%w%w%w%w").*(|r)*."`, but I think Lua is very simple (if it cannot have range support then I doubt it could do that).

Comment: @Mayron Will your input strings always contain only a single 
key-value pair?

Comment: It's hard to say if it "always" will, but for now yes. Thank you for expanding on your answer. I was busy working and only just checked!