# Format Validation Numeric Java?

Tags: java, regex, drools, number-formatting

I have a task to validate xml messages through Drools implementation in Java.

In a particular drool implementation I am asked to validate a field through n..5 format.

I am using regex for format checking like:

```
SampleText.matches("[0-9]")
```

For the n..**5**
It means the field max length is 5 'digits'?
Or it means that the field has to be always 5 digits in length?

I assume that it has to do with the max length is it right?

Merry Christmas and sorry for the dumb question
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly is `n..5`? A regex pattern?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify the exact number of characters/digits you can use `{}`, i.e.:

```
SampleText.matches("\d{5}") // matches 5 digits
```

Comment: Thank you Pedro that is what I was searching for . Specification team explained the requirement of the validation in a poor way. That's exactly what I needed . Merry Christmas