# regex in php: multiple possibilities

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I need to check that value takes the form (one or two or three any numbers and one or potential two any letters) example: 1B, 1AB, 45C, 791AS, 2, 324.
For now I have something like this:

```php
\d{1,3}[A-Z]{1,2}?/
```

but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus); the questions may relate to the same mechanism but this one contains a concrete example and a specific regex that is not working the way I expect.

Comment: So, both parts can go missing. Try `preg_match('~^(?!$)\d{0,3}[A-Z]{0,2}$~', $text, $matches)`.

Comment: Show your PHP code. Is the last `/` the delimiter or part of your actual regex?

Answer (score 1):

Why make the part for the characters so hard? You can set the occurrences to `{0,2}`:

```
\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,2}
```