# Filter strings which composed by 2 digits values in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataset as follows:

```
   id            vector_name
0   1            01,02,03,04
1   2            001,002,003
2   3               01,02,03
3   4                A, B, C
4   5          s01, s02, s02
5   6  E2702-2703,E2702-2703
6   7               03,05,06
7   8  05-08,09,10-12, 05-08
```

How could I write a regex to filter out the string rows in column `vector_name` which are not composed by **two digits** values: the correct format should be `01, 02, 03, ...` etc. Otherwise, returns `invalid vector name` for `check` column.

The expected result will be like this:

```py
   id            vector_name
0   1            01,02,03,04
1   2    invalid vector name
2   3               01,02,03
3   4    invalid vector name
4   5    invalid vector name
5   6    invalid vector name
6   7               03,05,06
7   8  05-08,09,10-12, 05-08
```

The pattern I used: `(\d+)(,\s*\d+)*`, but it consider `001,002,003` as valid.

How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Now, after you edited the title, it is not clear what you exactly need. Please come up with some code and update the question once you know your exact requirements. Strings of 10 digits can be checked with a simple `^\d{10}\Z` regex.

Comment: I updated the question, to simplify, I would like to filter out the rows of 10 digits split by comma.

Comment: So, remove the commas and check if there are 10 digits.

Comment: Maybe pattern like this `(\d+)(,\s*\d+)*`? But need for two digits delimited by `,`.

Comment: Aha, yes, something like `^\d{2}(?:,\s*\d{2}){4}\Z`. If you do not mind matching it when you have a trailing newline, ``^\d{2}(?:,\s*\d{2}){4}$`` will also do. If your requirement to have 10 digits is not actual, you may just use `^\d{2}(?:,\s*\d{2})*\Z`. Sorry, your expected result is somewhat misleading.

Comment: What does `{4}` stand for here?

Comment: `{4}` means four occurrences, repetitions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus

Comment: So, do you mean you need `df[df['vector_name'].str.contains(r'^\d{2}(?:,\s*\d{2})*$')] = np.nan`?

Comment: More like to if it's contre of `^\d{2}(?:,\s*\d{2})*\Z`, returns `invalid vector name` for `check`. Btw, why no `\Z` for pandas's `str.contains`?

Comment: `df[~df['vector_name'].str.contains(r'^\d{2}(?:,\s*\d{2})*\Z')] = "invalid vector name"`. Choose `$` or `\Z` depending on your real requirements.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, if I want to match `05-08,09,10-12,05-08` also as valid entries?

Comment: `^\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?(?:,\s*\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?)*\Z`?

Comment: Genius, it seems work out. Could you reopen my question?

Comment: Please confirm the expected output  is the one I changed to. If yes, the question is clear and can be reopened.

Comment: Yes, it is. But the ideal one maybe should be `df.loc[(df['vector_name'].str.contains(r'^\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?(?:,\s*\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?)*\Z')]), "check"] = "invalid vector name"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
^\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?(?:,\s*\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?)*\Z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qX8aT6/1). **Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?:-\d{2})?` - an optional sequence of `-` and two digits
- `(?:,\s*\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s*`  - 0 or more whitespaces
  - `\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?` - two digits and an optional sequence of `-` and two digits
- `\Z` - the very end of the string.

Python Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  'vector_name':
    [
      '01,02,03,04',
      '1002003',
      '01,02,03',
      'A, B, C',
      's01, s02, s02',
      'E2702-2703,E2702-2703',
      '03,05,06',
      '05-08,09,10-12, 05-08'
    ]
})
pattern = r'^\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?(?:,\s*\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?)*\Z'
df.loc[~df['vector_name'].str.contains(pattern), "check"] = "invalid vector name"
>>> df
   id            vector_name                check
0   1            01,02,03,04                  NaN
1   2                1002003  invalid vector name
2   3               01,02,03                  NaN
3   4                A, B, C  invalid vector name
4   5          s01, s02, s02  invalid vector name
5   6  E2702-2703,E2702-2703  invalid vector name
6   7               03,05,06                  NaN
7   8  05-08,09,10-12, 05-08                  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, if there are `NaN`s in `vector_name`, I want check be `NaN`s as well for them, then should I add `na=False` or `na=True`?

Comment: @ahbon What do you mean?

Comment: The problem has solved by a mask:`(df['vector_name'].notnull()) & (~df['vector_name'].astype(str).str.contains(pattern, na = False))`. :)