# powershell "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: regex, powershell, datetime

When i'm trying to parse a line in a IIS log file and pulling the datetime on the line, I'm getting the following error

> Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not
> recognized as a valid DateTime." At line:9 char:1
>
> - $dateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateTimeString, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
>   ```

here is my powershell code:

```
$line = '2020-12-23 02:01:16.244 -06:00 [Information] 2020-12-23T08:01:16.2446161Z:     [Error] Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out'
$dateTimeString = [regex]::Matches($line, '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')[0].Groups[1].Value
write-host "datetimestr:" $dateTimeString
$provider = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo "en-US"
$dateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateTimeString, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', $provider)

write-host $dateTime
$dateTime -f 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss' | write-host
```

i guess i need some fresh eyes to see what i'm missing.

notes:

- i've tried copying and pasting the string in the $line var to validate there are no strange chars in the datetime
- i have tried adding .trim to the $line and that didn't help
- i've also narrowed the regex pattern to '\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d' and parseexact() to ($dateTimeString, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $provider) and this doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$dateTimeString = [regex]::Match($line, '\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d').Value
```

Your `[regex]::Matches($line, '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')[0].Groups[1].Value` code matches a datetime substring into Group 0. You are trying to get Group 1 value by using `.Groups[1].Value`, but there is no capturing group defined in the pattern.

Note there is no need using `Matches` that fetches all occurrences in the string since all you need is the first match, which can be done with a mere `Match`.

Also, repeating `\d` four times in a regex is really redundant, you may use a `{4}` [*limiting quantifier*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus).

If you want to only find a match at the start of the string, add `^` at the beginning: `'^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to offer a simpler solution that doesn't require a complex regex:

```
$line = '2020-12-23 02:01:16.244 -06:00 [Information] 2020-12-23T08:01:16.2446161Z:     [Error] Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out'

[datetime] ((-split $line)[0..1] -join ' ')
```

- `-split`, the [string-splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) is used to split the line into whitespace-separated tokens, and the first two tokens (`[0..1]`) are joined back with a space.
- `[datetime]` is a *culture-invariant* way of converting a date-time string into a `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) instance; this culture-invariant way is based on the [`InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), which is based on the US-English culture.