# R regex quantifier dash vs. comma with {stringr} vs. {pointblank}

Tags: r, regex, validation, stringr, assertion

I'm noticing some odd behavior with R regex quantifiers written as either `{min, max}` (as recommend in the [stringr cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/strings.pdf)) vs. as `{min - max}`, when using the [pointblank](https://rich-iannone.github.io/pointblank/) package. I expect the regexes to work with `{min, max}` and fail with `{min - max}`. However, in the two examples below, one works with `{min, max}` and one works with `{min - max}`.

Example 1 works as expected: `pattern_comma` works and `pattern_dash` does **not**. But example 2 works unexpectedly: `doi_pattern_comma` does **not** work and `doi_pattern_dash` does work.

Any suggestions about this regex? Or might this be a bug in pointblank (in which case I can open an issue there)?

Thank you, SO community!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(pointblank)

# EXAMPLE 1
df1 <- tibble(x = c("123", "68"))
pattern_comma <- "^\\d{1,3}$"
pattern_dash <- "^\\d{1-3}$"

stringr::str_detect(df1$x, pattern_comma) #pass

#> [1] TRUE TRUE

stringr::str_detect(df1$x, pattern_dash)  #fail

#> Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)): Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL, context=`^\d{1-3}$`)


#pass
df1 %>% 
  pointblank::col_vals_regex(
    vars(x), 
    pattern_comma
  )

#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   x    
#>   <chr>
#> 1 123  
#> 2 68


#fail
df1 %>% 
  pointblank::col_vals_regex(
    vars(x), 
    pattern_dash
  )

#> Error: Exceedance of failed test units where values in `x` should have matched the regular expression: `^\d{1-3}$`.
#> The `col_vals_regex()` validation failed beyond the absolute threshold level (1).
#> * failure level (2) >= failure threshold (1)



# EXAMPLE 2
df2 <- tibble(doi = c("10.1186/s12872-020-01551-9", "10.1002/cpp.1968"))
doi_pattern_comma <- "^10\\.\\d{4,9}/[-.;()/:\\w\\d]+$"
doi_pattern_dash <- "^10\\.\\d{4-9}/[-.;()/:\\w\\d]+$"

stringr::str_detect(df2$doi, doi_pattern_comma) #pass

#> [1] TRUE TRUE

stringr::str_detect(df2$doi, doi_pattern_dash)  #fail

#> Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)): Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL, context=`^10\.\d{4-9}/[-.;()/:\w\d]+$`)


#fail
df2 %>% 
  col_vals_regex(
    vars(doi), 
    doi_pattern_comma
  )

#> Error: Exceedance of failed test units where values in `doi` should have matched the regular expression: `^10\.\d{4,9}/[-.;()/:\w\d]+$`.
#> The `col_vals_regex()` validation failed beyond the absolute threshold level (1).
#> * failure level (2) >= failure threshold (1)


#pass
df2 %>% 
  col_vals_regex(
    vars(doi), 
    doi_pattern_dash
  )

#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   doi                       
#>   <chr>                     
#> 1 10.1186/s12872-020-01551-9
#> 2 10.1002/cpp.1968
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Where did you learn the `{n-m}` syntax is supported by `col_vals_regex`? `df1 %>%  pointblank::col_vals_regex(vars(x),pattern_comma)` works.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, `pattern_comma` works in example 1 (as expected) but `doi_pattern_comma` does not work in example 2 (and `doi_pattern_dash` does). That's the mystery to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not doubt: `{min-max}` [quantifier does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus), **you need to use
`{min,max}`**. `\d{4-9}` throws an exception (try it with `sub` and you will get *`invalid regular expression '\d{4-9}', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'`* ).

Next, the second issue is that the regex is parsed with the default TRE regex engine, and you can't use shorthand character classes like `\w` or `\W` inside bracket expressions there, so you **need to use `[:alnum:]_` instead of `\w` inside square brackets**.

Now, that you know the right regex:

```r
"^10\\.\\d{4,9}/[-.;()/:[:alnum:]_]+$"
```

you can dive deeper.

You can see what results you get if you use `test_col_vals_regex`:

```r
> df2 %>% test_col_vals_regex(vars(doi), "^10\\.\\d{4,9}/[-.;()/:[:alnum:]_]+$")
[1] TRUE
> df2 %>% test_col_vals_regex(vars(doi), "^10\\.\\d{4-9}/[-.;()/:[:alnum:]_]+$")
[1] NA
> df2 %>% test_col_vals_regex(vars(doi), "^10\\.\\d{4,9}/[-.;()/:\\w]+$")
[1] FALSE
> df2 %>% test_col_vals_regex(vars(doi), "^10\\.\\d{4-9}/[-.;()/:\\w]+$")
[1] NA
```

So, all the cases when the regex is malformed return `NA` and the validation for those items is skipped, passing them in the end.

**CONCLUSION**: Always test your regex patterns for validity before using them in `col_vals_regex`.